# Google map licence to display israel map

Tags: google-maps

What is the process to get google map licence to display map of israel in higher resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give OpenStreetMap project a try. It's free and has a license which allows you to use it in commercial projects (provided that you give credit where due).

The project's home page is http://www.openstreetmap.org/